# Broke ping in Kali

Tags: kali-linux, ping

I accidentally corrupted ping in Kali linux. I was messing around and and opened ping with vi, and I must have changed the file instead of exiting like I was trying to.

If i run ping local host or any host it gives "segmentation fault".

How can I fix the ping utility?

I thought doing something like

```
apt-get iputils-ping
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: boot a live cd of kali and copy the binary over

Comment: What do you mean by "that doesn't seem to work"? What error messages have you got? It will be helpful if you clarify in the question. Finally, Kali are for those who are already familiar with general Linux distros.

Comment: output:
E: Invalid operation iputils-ping

Comment: If I booted up a live cd could I just copy ping and then replace it in current system?

Comment: Also I'm using Kali in the class that I'm taking where we are learning about linux basics at same time. Thanks

Comment: If that class isn't requiring the use of Kali, Kali is by far the worst possible choice of distro. If it is, that class is not a good class. But anyway, it's `apt-get install some-package`, not just `apt-get some-pckage`

Comment: @G-Man I don't see the point in penalizing the use of Kali when you can do this on any version of Linux and using apt-get is similar on Kali to other distros. If we're talking about setting up wifi drivers or something sure.

Comment: The class is network security. I've used various distro's of linux for a decade. I've just never accidentally screwed up a tool like ping before and didn't know the best course to fix it. I also initially didn't know that ping is called iputils-ping. How would one know that without searching on the internet? How could I determine inside linux that ping is iputils-ping?

Comment: "How could I determine inside linux that ping is iputils-ping?" That depends on your system (specifically, your package manager). In your case, it's probably `dpkg -S $(command -v ping)`. On Arch, it's `pacman -Qo $(command -v ping)`

Answer (score 4):

Try the command `apt-get install --reinstall iputils-ping` which would reinstall the files of the package except for the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured this out and ping works now.

```
apt-get remove iputils-ping

apt-get update && apt-get install iputils-ping
```

And now it works!
Thanks for the help!